# Вынос часто повторяющегося html-кода в отдельный Layout файл

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout

Есть несколько одинаковых модальных окон, которые хотелось бы вынести в отдельный файл с возможностью передавать на них необходимые параметры с основной страницы. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: на ответ не тянет, поэтому напишу здесь: я делал частичное представление в которое передавал заголовок, текст, для верстки использую bootstrap. интересно как это делают более опытные коллеги, так что плюсую

Answer (score 1):

В ASP MVC существуют такие понятия как EditorTemplate, DisplayTemplate, это то, что вам нужно. Так же вам может пригодится PartialView.

Comment: может Вы распишите более подробно с примером кода, либо приведете ссылку где можно посмотреть с примером, если Вам не сложно конечно

Comment: На SO не особо приветствуются ссылки, а писать тут выйдет многовато. Данные понятия хорошо гуглятся. На msdn так же присутствуют примеры.

Answer (score 0):

Выход бы найден с помощью создания отдельного класса HtmlHelper. Внутри него создан метод, который возвращает MvcHtmlString. Это значит, что метод позволяет с помощью кода на C# генерировать html-элементы. В методе достаточно прописать генерацию повторяющегося. На View необходимо будет  вызывать этот метод в нужных местах, передавая в него необходимые значения.

Вспомогательный класс:

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CreateHtmlRepeatedText(this HtmlHelper html, string str)
    {
        //Создаём тег "а"
        TagBuilder tagA = new TagBuilder("a");
        //Добавим тегу класс
        tagA.AddCssClass("myLinkClass");
        //Добавим тегу атрибут "имя"
        tagA.MergeAttribute("name", "myLink");
        //Вернём на View html-строку
        return new MvcHtmlString(tagA.ToString());
    }
}
```

Html-код:

```
@using ProjectName.Helpers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>@MyHelper.CreateHtmlRepeatedText(Html, ViewBag.StringWithLink1)</div>
    <div>@MyHelper.CreateHtmlRepeatedText(Html, ViewBag.StringWithLink2)</div>
    <div>@MyHelper.CreateHtmlRepeatedText(Html, ViewBag.StringWithLink3)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Если необходимо создать более сложный Html-код, например, где есть вложенные теги, можно использовать свойство **InnerHtml** для родительского тега:

```
TagBuilder innerSpan = new TagBuilder("span");
innerSpan.MergeAttribute("value", "1");
tagA.InnerHtml += innerSpan.ToString();
```

Однако, меня всё ещё интересует вопрос, насколько хорошее это решение, не будет ли генерация html кода с помощью C# медленнее, чем изначально прописанный html-код?